# Html parsing with JSoup

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse the html of the following URL:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-050-thermal-energy-fall-2002/

to obtain the text of the "< p >" tag which contains the name of an instructor. The required information is located inside "< p >" tags but I am unable to retrieve the tags using JSoup. I have no idea what I am doing wrong because when I save the  tag in an Element object lets call it 'b' and I call b.getAllElements() it doesn't show

as one of the elements. Isn't that what the getAllElements() method of Jsoup does? If not could someone please explain to me the hierarchy that I am obviously missing as the parser is not able to locate the

tag which contains the text that I require which in this case is "Prof. Zoltan Spakovszky".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void getHomePageLinks()
{
    String html = "http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-050-thermal-energy-fall-2002/";
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements bodies = doc.select("body");

    for(Element body : bodies )
    {
        System.out.println(body.getAllElements());
    }

}
```

the output is:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-050-thermal-energy-fall-2002/

isn't it supposed to print out all the elements within the body tag in the document?

Comment: A code snippet might be helpful.

Comment: Your code prints the the body and all its content. However, if you only want to print the body tag (and all its childs) you can use this instead: `System.out.println(doc.body());` (see my answer below about getting the `doc`)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about JSoup, but it seems like if you wanted the instructors name you could access it with something like:

```
Element instructor = doc.select("div.chpstaff div p");
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you, but +1 from me because your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

may be u already solved but i worked on it so cant resist to submit

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
public class JavaApplication17 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
   String url = "http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-050-thermal-energy-   fall-2002/";
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
  Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
  for(Element p : paragraphs)
    System.out.println(p.text());

} 
catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication17.class.getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
  }
}

is it what u meant?
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short example:

```
// Connect to the website and parse it into a document
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-050-thermal-energy-fall-2002/").get();

// Select all elements you need (se below for documentation)
Elements elements = doc.select("div[class=chpstaff] p");

// Get the text of the first element
String instructor = elements.first().text();

// eg. print the result
System.out.println(instructor);
```

Take a look at the documentation of the jsoup selector api here: [Jsoup Codebook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
Its not very difficult to use but very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-050-thermal-energy-fall-2002/").get();

        Elements elements = document.select("p");
        System.out.println(elements.html());
```

You can select all tags using Selector property of Jsoup. It will return the text and tags of

.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Elements ele=doc.select("p");
      ' String text=ele.text();
        System.out.println(text);
```

Try this I think it will work